# Django app throwing errors on deployment to production using virtualenv, wsgi and apache

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Trying to take my application to production has been hectic.

I get syntax error when i check apache's error log after i make a call to the site.

I have done everything as seen in different sources online, yet i can't get passed the error. The major problem is, i don't even get why a syntax error from Django's internal function when the app ordinarily works on development without hitches.

**The Error i get is as seen below**

```
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179813 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]   File "/var/www/html/app_folder/app/index.wsgi", line 29, in <module>
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179860 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179869 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]   File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179900 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179907 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]   File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 2, in <module>
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179954 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]     import functools
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179982 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]   File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 254
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179986 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]     cls, func, *args = args
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179988 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0]                ^
[Tue Jun 05 08:13:34.179990 2018] [:error] [pid 1390] [remote ::1:0] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Here is the content for my wsgi file:**

```
import os
import sys
import site
#import django

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/app_folder')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/app_folder/app')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))


import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Django version 2.0.4
Python version 3.6
```

**Apache Config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
    ServerName test.server.com
    ServerAlias test.server.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=5 python-path=/var/html/www/app_folder/app:/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.6/ threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup app

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/app_folder/app/index.wsgi
    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/app_folder/app/static/

    <Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Location>
```

Your help would be grossly appreciated as this is an emergency.

Comment: You can't force mod_wsgi which is compiled for one version of Python, to use a virtual environment of a different Python version. Your mod_wsgi is likely for Python 2.7. Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html and check what version of Python your mod_wsgi is for by reading http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: Why not `nginx`? It is simple to deploy.

Comment: I have found that @GrahamDumpleton is right. The mode_wsgi in use if for python 2.7 and not python3.6. The issue i have now is how to uninstall it for that of 3.6 in centos. Only Apache is allowed due to company police.

Comment: Disable the mod_wsgi module, or uninstall it completely. Then use ``pip install`` method to install up to date mod_wsgi with correct Python. See https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/ Use the method explained right at end for connecting it with your existing Apache installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrahamDumpleton, you were a lot of help. You saved me a whole lot of headache.